# I want to call my script when command not found in bash (cmder)?

Tags: bash, shell, sh, conemu, cmder

If the Command is not found in bash(cmder).
Then i need to call my batch or shell file. 
and execute custom code to print result instead of default
`bash: foo: command not found`

Is there any settings in cmder or any possible other way to achieve this case.
If there is any other console emulator that can able to achieve this case?

Answer (score 0):

you can check if command is callable with

```
if ! type COMMAND &>/dev/null; then
   # not callable - here your script
fi
```

or after the call, if command not found (exitcode =  127)

```
COMMAND
if [[ "$?" == 127 ]]; then
   # command unknown  - here your script
fi
```

Comment: thanks for sharing. I seen this scrip. But where should I write this to achieve my behaviour.